# syntax error : missing ')' before 'constant'

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have some syntax problems that I don't know how to fix. I'm trying to build some functions to matrix, can someone help me resolve those problems?

```
1>c:\documents and settings\one\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hw3\hw3\q2.c(11): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'constant'
1>c:\documents and settings\one\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hw3\hw3\q2.c(11): error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before 'constant'
1>c:\documents and settings\one\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hw3\hw3\q2.c(11): error C2059: syntax error : '<Unknown>'
1>c:\documents and settings\one\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hw3\hw3\q2.c(11): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>c:\documents and settings\one\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hw3\hw3\q2.c(12): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'constant'
1>c:\documents and settings\one\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hw3\hw3\q2.c(12): error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before 'constant'
1>c:\documents and settings\one\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hw3\hw3\q2.c(12): error C2059: syntax error : '<Unknown>'
1>c:\documents and settings\one\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hw3\hw3\q2.c(12): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>c:\documents and settings\one\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hw3\hw3\q2.c(13): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'constant'
1>c:\documents and settings\one\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hw3\hw3\q2.c(13): error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before 'constant'
1>c:\documents and settings\one\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hw3\hw3\q2.c(13): error C2059: syntax error : '<Unknown>'
1>c:\documents and settings\one\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hw3\hw3\q2.c(13): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>c:\documents and settings\one\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hw3\hw3\q2.c(27): warning C4013: 'initMatrix' undefined; assuming extern returning int
1>c:\documents and settings\one\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hw3\hw3\q2.c(29): warning C4013: 'completeMatrix' undefined; assuming extern returning int
1>c:\documents and settings\one\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hw3\hw3\q2.c(30): warning C4013: 'displayMatrix' undefined; assuming extern returning int before 'constant'
1>c:\documents and settings\one\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hw3\hw3\q2.c(146): error C2059: syntax error : '<Unknown>'
1>c:\documents and settings\one\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hw3\hw3\q2.c(146): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define N 10
#define MAX_CHAR 9
int checkString(char *str);
void replacingLetters(char *str);
int countWords(char *str);
int * initMatrix(int M, int N);
void completeMatrix(char *str,int *arr,int M, int N);
void displayMatrix(int *arr,int M, int N);
int main() 
{
    int *res;
    int numOfWords;
    char inputFromUser[N*MAX_CHAR];
    printf("Please insert a string : ");
    gets(inputFromUser);

    if (1 == checkString(inputFromUser))
    {
        replacingLetters(inputFromUser);
        numOfWords = countWords(inputFromUser);

     *res = initMatrix(26,numOfWords);

        completeMatrix(inputFromUser,res,26,numOfWords);
        displayMatrix(res,26,numOfWords);
    }

    return 0;
}

int checkString(char *str)
{
    int stringLen = 0;
    int i = 0;

    stringLen = strlen(str);

    for (i = 0 ; i < stringLen ; ++i)
    {
        if ((str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') || 
            (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z') ||
            (str[i] == ' '))
        {
            continue;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

void replacingLetters(char *str)
{
    int stringLen = 0;
    int i = 0;

    stringLen = strlen(str);

    for (i = 0 ; i < stringLen ; ++i)
    {
        if (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z')
        {
            str[i] = str[i] - 'A' + 'a';
        }
    }
}

int countWords(char *str)
{
    int stringLen = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int numberOfWords = 0;
    int isNewWord = 1;

    stringLen = strlen(str);

    for (i = 0 ; i < stringLen ; ++i)
    {
        if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
        {
            if (isNewWord == 1)
            {
                numberOfWords++;
                isNewWord = 0;
            }
        }

        if (str[i] == ' ')
        {
            isNewWord = 1;
        }
    }

    return numberOfWords;
}

int * initMatrix(int M, int N)
{
    int * retVal = 0;
    int i,j;
    retVal = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) *N *M);

    for ( i = 0 ; i < N ; ++i)
    {
        for ( j = 0 ; j < M ; ++j)
        {
            retVal[i*M + j] = 0;
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}

void completeMatrix(char *str,int *arr,int M, int N)
{
    int numOfWords = 0;
    int wordIdx = 0;
    int idx = 0;
    int idxInWord = 1;

    if (1 == checkString(str))
    {
        replacingLetters(str);
        numOfWords = countWords(str);

        for (wordIdx = 0; wordIdx < numOfWords ; ++wordIdx)
        {
            idxInWord = 1;
            while((str[idx] != 0) && (str[idx] != ' '))
            {
                arr[wordIdx * M +  str[idx] - 'a'] = arr[wordIdx * M +  str[idx] - 'a']*10 + idxInWord;
                idx++;
                idxInWord++;
            }

            idx++;
        }
    }
}

void displayMatrix(int *arr,int M, int N)
{
    int i,j;

    for ( i = 0 ; i < _N ; ++i)
    {
        for ( j = M -1 ; j >= 0 ; --j)
        {
            printf("%d ",_arr[i*M + j]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: `int * initMatrix(int M, int N);` : `N` replace with `10` by `#define N 10` at preprocess phase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`#define` is a [preprocessor MACRO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) which acts as a *textual replacement* in the preprocesssing stage. In your case, with a MACRO like

```
#define N 10
```

and then with a function like

```
void displayMatrix(int *arr,int M, int N);
```

it turns out to be

```
void displayMatrix(int *arr,int M, int 10);  //note the int 10 part
```

which is basically replacing all occurrences of `N` with `10` and after which it becomes illegal. You need to have an `int` variable type for function parameter, not an `int` literal.

Change all occurrences of `int N` in function parameter to some other variable name.

That said,

1. `gets()` suffers seriously from buffer overflow issue. Use [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead.
2. [Do not cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.
3. Recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`.

Comment: BTW: There's also have some define in window.h that may be included by third-party library. such as : _WIN32 _DEBUG NDEBUG ERROR ... So please be patient to search whether some keyword conflict.